# How to access custom bpmn extension elements with camunda java api?

Tags: java, api, camunda, bpmn

I have a Bpmn file with an extension element like this.

```
  <bpmn:extensionElements>
    <zeebe:taskDefinition type="customer-interaction-service" retries="0" />
    <zeebe:taskHeaders>
      <zeebe:header key="operation" value="save" />
      <zeebe:header key="@type" value="Organization[]" />
      <zeebe:header key="updateReliesOnReferredTypes" value="@Customer.engagedParty" />
    </zeebe:taskHeaders>
  </bpmn:extensionElements>
```

I want to access the header elements and get keys and values.
I followed [this tutorial for cmn](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/cmmn-model-api/typed-custom-elements) but Bpmn api did not register my custom classes.
You can clone full code from [here](https://github.com/hamidrezaabroshan/access-custom-extension-element-with-camunda-bpmn-model-api-java.git)
I copppy some important parts here.

### Main class:

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/dclm-addservice.bpmn");
        BpmnModelInstance model =CustomBpmn.readModelFromStream(is );
        ServiceTask serviceTask=model.getModelElementById("ServiceTask_1jn441o");
        int count=serviceTask.getExtensionElements().getElementsQuery().filterByType(TaskHeaders.class).count();
        System.out.println(count);
        count=serviceTask.getExtensionElements().getElementsQuery().count();
        System.out.println(count);
        
    }

}
```

result:
0
2

### When filtering by TaskHeaders.class, it has 0 result.
customBpmn

```
public class CustomBpmn extends Bpmn {
    public static CustomBpmn INSTANCE = new CustomBpmn();
    public CustomBpmn() {
        super();
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }
    @Override
    protected void doRegisterTypes(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
      super.doRegisterTypes(modelBuilder);
      System.out.println("registering");
      HeaderImpl.registerType(modelBuilder);
      TaskHeadersImpl.registerType(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

### header interface

```
public interface Header extends BpmnModelElementInstance  {
    public String getKey();
    public void setKey(String key);
    public String getValue();
    public void setValue(String value);
}
```

### TaskHeaders interface

```
public interface TaskHeaders extends BpmnModelElementInstance {
    Collection<Header> getHeaders();
    void addHeader(Header header);
    boolean addHeaders(List<Header> headers);
    List<Header> findByKey(String key);
}
```

### HeaderImpl

```
public class HeaderImpl extends BpmnModelElementInstanceImpl implements Header {
    protected static Attribute<String> keyAttribute;
    protected static Attribute<String> valueAttribute;
    public static void registerType(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        ModelElementTypeBuilder typeBuilder = modelBuilder.defineType(Header.class, HEADER)
                .namespaceUri(ZEEBE_SCHEMA)
                .instanceProvider(new ModelTypeInstanceProvider<Header>() {
                    public Header newInstance(ModelTypeInstanceContext instanceContext) {
                        return new HeaderImpl(instanceContext);
                    }
                });
        keyAttribute =typeBuilder.stringAttribute(KEY_NAME)
                .namespace(ZEEBE_SCHEMA)
                .build();
        valueAttribute =typeBuilder.stringAttribute(VALUE_NAME)
                .namespace(ZEEBE_SCHEMA)
                .build();
        typeBuilder.build();
    }
    public HeaderImpl(ModelTypeInstanceContext instanceContext) {
        super(instanceContext);
    }


//some getter and setters.
```

### TaskHeadersImple

```
public class TaskHeadersImpl extends BpmnModelElementInstanceImpl implements TaskHeaders {
    protected static ChildElementCollection<Header> headerCollection;
    public static void registerType(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        ModelElementTypeBuilder typeBuilder = modelBuilder.defineType(TaskHeaders.class, TASK_HEADERS)
                .namespaceUri(ZEEBE_SCHEMA)
                .instanceProvider(new ModelTypeInstanceProvider<TaskHeaders>() {
                    public TaskHeaders newInstance(ModelTypeInstanceContext instanceContext) {
                        return new TaskHeadersImpl(instanceContext);
                    }
                });
        SequenceBuilder sequenceBuilder = typeBuilder.sequence();
        headerCollection =sequenceBuilder.elementCollection(Header.class)
                .build();
        typeBuilder.build();
    }
    public TaskHeadersImpl(ModelTypeInstanceContext instanceContext) {
        super(instanceContext);
    }


//some getters and setters.
```

Thanks.

Edit:
I could access TaskHeaders by using Zeebe java api instead of Camunda java api but the above question is still valid because TaskHeaders are not custom bpmn elements for zeebe modeler java api but are custom extension for Camunda.

Comment: The [post](https://forum.camunda.io/t/access-custom-extension-elements-with-the-bpmn-model-api/3897) may be help for this question.